# htaccess will only redirect web pages i.e php and html

Tags: image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to use hotlink protection with my website and the code doesn't appear to work (I copied this off a site)

So I tried redirecting everything with to an image what is hosted on a separate website to see if the rewrite was working and I found that the rewriterule would only redirect web pages such as a php file or html

here is the code I used to redirect all files:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.filetransit.com/images/screen/8d3171cb63e905f67bb7685f4b033bfb_AQL_htpasswd_and_htaccess_Password_Manager.jpg [NC]
```

And i have turned the rewriteEngine on

Comment: Please provide the entire htaccess. The code above doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a hotlink protection to any url on your webpage you may use `HTTP_REFERER`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([a-z0-9]+\.)?example\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$            http://example.org/image.jpg       [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: yes i know how to do hotlink protection but for some reason the rewrite rule only works with web pages not images

Comment: Did you try something like this `RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]` ?

Comment: This rule : `RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.filetransit.com/images/screen/8d3171cb63e905f67bb7685f4b033bfb_AQL_htpasswd_and_htaccess_Password_Manager.jpg [NC]` for some reason only works on webpages not css or images, I haven't used any RewriteCond. and I want it to work with images

Comment: It should work as `.*` matches everything. Just to try everything out  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/image.jpg [R,NC]`